# Flexbox make content wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a sidebar + content layout.
The sidebar is not always there.
Inside the content I have a div with a large width (from a slider).

Any idea on how to limit the panel-wrapper so we don't have any overflow on the content itself ?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;

}

.sidebar {
  background: #aaa;
}

.content {

}

.panel-wrapper {
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  background: pink;
  
  width: 5000px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus suscipit possimus facilis exercitationem blanditiis incidunt minus voluptatem modi veritatis molestias inventore provident deleniti quod 
      <div class="panel-wrapper">
        <div class="panel">
          <div>item1</div>
          <div>item2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      vitae cupiditate delectus quam, dolorum rerum!</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your .wrapper is full width. So first you should give it max-width.
Let's say we give it a `max-width: "100vw";`
then just determine the width for your sidebar and content accordingly:

> width: 300px;
>
> width: calc(100vw - 300px);

here is an example of css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 100vw; // Setting a width to your container
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 300px; // setting a width to your sidebar
  background: #aaa;
}

.content {
  width: calc(100vw - 300px); // and the width to your content, that depends on width of the sidebar and the whole area .wrapper
}

.panel-wrapper {
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;

  background: pink;

  width: 5000px;
}
```